# Convert array with 8bit value to string with char (no charcode)

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, fromcharcode

I found an elegant code to converts ArrayBuffer into charCode.

But I need char, instead of charCode.

```
function ab2s (buf) {
  var view = new Uint8Array (buf);
  return Array.prototype.join.call (view, ",");
}
```

I tried

```
return Array.prototype.join.call (view, function() {String.fromCharCode(this)});
```

But this is crap.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between char and charcode? Can you please provide some example input, the expected output and what happens for you instead?

Comment: Why did you pass a callback function to `Array::join`? The only thing it takes is a delimiter!

Comment: Charcode (ASCII code) numbers 65 66 67 => A B C

Comment: I have to rewrite my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> return Array.prototype.join.call (view, function() {String.fromCharCode(this)});
> ```
>
> But this is crap.

Obviously, since [Array::join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) does not take a callback to transform each element but only the separator by which the elements should be joined.

Instead, to transform every element before joining them you would use [Array::map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
return Array.prototype.map.call(view, function(charcode) {
    return String.fromCharCode(charcode);
}).join('');
```

However, there is a much easier solution, as [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) does take multiple arguments:

```
return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, view);
```

Comment: Output in hex editor: Original : '00 00 9C BO 6D 6F | ....mo'      From your script '00 00 C2 9C C2 B0 6D 6F | ......mo' Problem with ASCII code > 127   Second script have same output and limit 256kb string

Comment: You did not say anything about file I/O. I don't know what you're doing, but JS does use Unicode for its strings, so when writing to a file you usually get some UTF encoding.

Comment: 1Byte (8bit) greater than 127 spread at 2bytes. Is it possible to somehow get around this?

Comment: Write as ASCII? As I said, those aren't "bytes", but Unicode "characters"! If you're just caring about binaries, then strings are the wrong tool to work with. If you've got further problems, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include the IO code there.

Comment: In JavaScript it looks OK, transformation occurs after sending to the server, so the solution is to adjust it in PHP. Is able this set in headers? Octet-stream?

Comment: No, you should send the correct headers on the client side. As I said, please post a new question and we will help you there.

Comment: I solved this by converting again to ArrayBuffer before upload.

Comment: Huh? Why convert forth and back, instead of just sending what you have?

Comment: Convert ArrayBuffer to byteString is only for encrypt string.